# Get Specific Value from JSONArray

Tags: android, json

i got an jsonarray:

```
  [
    {
        "ean": "8020079127",
        "nr": "100",
        "name": "Name1"
    },
    {
        "ean": "8026180222",
        "nr": "4",
        "name": "Name2"
    },
    {
        "ean": "6577426092",
        "nr": "1",
        "name": "Name3"
    }
]
```

I need the value from "nr" depending on the "ean" means:
I got the ean 8026180222 (as string) and need the value from the "nr" (here "4"). how I can get it?
its possible without iterate over the whole array?

thank you

Comment: Android provides all thing well described, Just need to look for it [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)

Comment: Your answer is here: https://queception.com/question.php?question=117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
     // Use a map to store ean,nr (as key/value)
     HashMap<String, String> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

     // Load the data from json 
     JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(yourJsonString);

     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        String ean = jsonObj.getString("ean");
        String nr = jsonObj.getString("nr");
        String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
        jsonMap.put(ean, nr);  // here you put ean as key and nr as value
     }
```

To retrieve an **nr** value of a specific **ean** just call: `jsonMap.get(yourEAN);`

Example: `String nr = jsonMap.get("8026180222");`

Comment: Your answer is here: https://queception.com/question.php?question=117

Answer (score 0):

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

JsonObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

                    Log.d("Tag", json.toString());

                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        JSONArray jsnObj;
                        try {
                            jsnObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_ARRAY);
                            JSONObject obj = jsnObj
                                    .getJSONObject(1);
        String nr = obj.getString(TAG_NR);

                            }
                        Catch(Exception ex){}
                 }

          }
```

If you want array you can use loops in json array.....................Hope it will help

Just define

```
   private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
   private static final String TAG_NR = "nr";
   private static final String TAG_ARRAY = "array_name";
```